# How to get collection of ng-model Checkbox in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

Here is my data:

```
var fields = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Model'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Price'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Condition'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Ads Type'}
];
```

Here is my view code:

```
 <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="field in fields"
               ng-model="field.id"
               ng-checked="field.id">
               {{ field.name }}
 </ion-checkbox>
 <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="updateField()">
    Update SubCategory Field
 </button>
```

Here is my controller Code

```
$scope.updateField = function(){
   // How can I get an Array of any Checked rows 
   // Expected result is: [2, 4]
}
```

[image: I'd Like to get Id of Price and Ads Type as an Array]

I have tried this:

```
console.log($scope.field.id);
```

and the error through

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: where are you putting that console.log statement anyways ?

Comment: You should not use `var fields = [...]` but rather `$scope.fields = [...]`. And then you access your fields like `$scope.fields[INDEX].checked`.

Comment: I've put the console log inside the function, It's just a sample array, that's why it's populated into the checkbox. I just want to retrieve it back after clicking the button.

Comment: map ng-model with "field.id" instead of ' ng-model="field.checked"'

Comment: shouldn't there be a property "checked" in your "fields" ?

Comment: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/lOSaa9k7EEpgriz4AmaZ?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script   src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl ">

   <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="field in fields"
               ng-model="field.checked"
               ng-checked="field.checked">
               {{ field.name }} 
 </input>
 <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="updateField()">
    Update SubCategory Field
 </button>


          {{ selectedItems  | json }} 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])

app.controller('ctrl', function($filter, $scope){

 $scope.fields = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Model'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Price'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Condition'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Ads Type'}
];

$scope.updateField = function(){

    var p = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fields.length; i++) {
       var item = $scope.fields[i];
       if ( item.checked) {
        p.push(item )  
       }

    }

    $scope.selectedItems = p;
}

});
```

Comment: thanks, i'm jealous of not being a great programmer now.